# R - Cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(type='PSOCK', spec=spec) - crashing windows

Tags: r, windows, parallel-processing

I am trying to take advantage of parallel computing. I am using the code found here https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/11/running-r-clusters-on-an-amd-threadripper-3990x-in-windows-10/

`

```
a <- list( host='localhost', user='', ncore = 62,
 rscript = 'C:\\Progra~1\\MS\\ROpen\\R-  4.0.2\\bin\\x64\\BaseRScript.bat')

b <- list( host='localhost', user='', ncore = 62,
 rscript = 'C:\\Progra~1\\MS\\ROpen\\R-4.0.2\\bin\\x64\\BaseRScript_1.bat')

machineAddresses <- list( a, b )

spec <- lapply(machineAddresses,
   function(machine) { rep(list(list( host=machine$host,
    rscript=machine$rscript ) ), machine$ncore )})

spec <- unlist(spec,recursive=FALSE)

Cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(type='PSOCK', spec=spec)
```

`

However, **on the last line**, R takes a long time, and then Windows crashes. I tried to use less cores with the same result.

Comment: Curious, have you tried fixing the typo in the definition of the `a` variable? Or do you really have two separate directories, both `C:/Progra~1/MS/ROpen/R-  4.0.2/` and `C:/Progra~1/MS/ROpen/R-4.0.2/`?

Comment: Yes, I actually corrected that to my path, indeed in this example there is this typo.

Comment: Have you tried with less cores?

Comment: Yes, I did with 30.